# Shiny: ignoreNULL not working when the eventReactive function take output from another eventReactive function as input?

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a Shiny application that first generate the data and then plot the data based on the selected inputs (which column to plot, what color to use etc).

I am expecting that the data only generated after the user click action button (action button 1), and the plot will be created together with data based on the default selected inputs. And when the user want to change the inputs, they will need to click another action button (action button 2) to update the plot. When user click action button 2, data should not be re-generated.

Is there a way to do it?

I've tried the ignoreNULL for eventReactive(), but setting ignoreNULL = FALSE to the plotting reactive function does not seem to work when for the data generating reactive function it is set to be TRUE

Following is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton('data', 'Generate Random Data'),
      hr(),
      radioButtons("column", label = "Select Column: ", choices = c("x", "y")),
      actionButton('plot', 'Plot')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("result")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  #### read in data
  dataReactive <- eventReactive(input$data, {
    dt <- data.frame("x" = rnorm(100), "y" = rnorm(100, mean = 100))
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  plotReactive <- eventReactive(input$plot, {
    dt <- dataReactive()
    p <- hist(dt[[input$column]])
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  output$result <- renderPlot({
    p <- plotReactive()
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm expecting that the application will start with empty page, and when first click the Generate Random Data button the histogram will be displayed without click the Plot button. But when select column is changed, then Plot button has to be clicked to update the plot.

The reason is because the actual application that I'm working on actually takes long time to pull data from database. So I don't want the application to automatically start before user is prepared. And I don't want to pull data every time user wants to change the plotting settings since all plots use the same data.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are expecting?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton('data', 'Generate Random Data'),
      hr(),
      radioButtons("column", label = "Select Column: ", choices = c("x", "y")),
      actionButton('plot', 'Plot')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("result")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  #### read in data
  dataReactive <- eventReactive(input$data, {
    print('generationg')
    dt <- data.frame("x" = rnorm(100), "y" = rnorm(100, mean = 100))
  })
  plotReactive <- eventReactive({
      input$plot
      input$data
    }, {
    dt <- dataReactive()
    p <- hist(dt[[input$column]])
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  output$result <- renderPlot({
    p <- plotReactive()
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```